# Expected Value of drawing 10 tickets

Tags: expectation

In a lottery, 10 tickets are drawn at random out of 50 tickets numbered from 1 to 50. What is the expected value of the sum of numbers on the drawn tickets?

**My approach** -

If after drawing a ticket, if it was replaced, then it can be easily solved.

Then, E(X) = 1*(1/50) + 2*(1/50) + ..... + 50*(1/50) = 51/2

However, I'm assuming that the tickets are not replaced because replacing a ticket does not make any sense. So, in that scenario, the expected value of any event (except the first one) is dependent on the expected values of the previous events. I can't figure out how to find expectation in this case or would it be the same as (51/2)*50 and I'm missing something.

Comment: Is there *any* reason to think that the probability of the second drawn ticket to be numbered by e.g. a $7$ differs from the probability of the first drawn ticket to be numbered by a $7$?... Think this over to sharpen your intuition. The answer is :"no".This in spite of not replacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a trick that is useful when finding the expectation of a sum: *expectation is linear*.

Specifically, let $X_i$ be the value of the $i$th ticket you draw. Then
$$
E(X_1+X_2 + \cdots +X_{10}) = E(X_1) + E(X_2) + \cdots + E(X_{10})
$$
In other words, while the probability distribution of the random variable $Y = X_1+X_2 + \cdots +X_{10}$ cares that you don't replace tickets, and this can make calculations complicated, *expectation* doesn't care. So it can still be as easily solved.